# Python/Django - Same Try / Except

Tags: python, django

Actually I have 3 try / Except in the same view, because I'm using 3 objects in my models. The problem is I'm reapeating in my code and I don't like that.

Here is the code :

```
    try:
    menuDetail = Menu.objects.get(id=menuId)
except Menu.DoesNotExist:
    return logoutUser(request)
try:
    menuItem = MenuItem.objects.get(id=menuItemId)
except MenuItem.DoesNotExist:
    return logoutUser(request)
try:
    menuItemProd = MenuItemProd.objects.get(id=menuItemId)
except MenuItemProd.DoesNotExist:
    return logoutUser(request)
```

I have this error when I added the third exception : global name 'logoutUser' is not defined.

Do you have an idea on the problem ? Thank you for taking time on my problem :)

Comment: Where youre logoutUser func coming from?

Comment: It's a function of logout that I call in another view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting here for readability.

You can rewrite your code as so :

```
try:
    menuDetail = Menu.objects.get(id=menuId)
    menuItem = MenuItem.objects.get(id=menuItemId)
    menuItemProd = MenuItemProd.objects.get(id=menuItemId)
except (Menu.DoesNotExist, MenuItem.DoesNotExist, MenuItemProd.DoesNotExist):
    return logoutUser(request)
```

Comment: I still have my error but for the topic of reading it's ok :) Thank you, I'm gonna write another topic for the problem of global name 'logoutUser' is not defined.

Comment: Link the topic here, maybe I can help. Try to be more precise with that problem :)